# Formulario de solicitud de pedidos en Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web en Django para realizar pedidos internos en una empresa. Lo que no puedo encontrar y agradecería me indiquen donde puedo buscar o si conocen algún proyecto similar es como hacer para que la cantidad de items en el formulario se vaya incrementando a medida que se agregan items al pedido. Es decir que mientras el pedio 1 pueda tener 2 items con su descripción y cantidad, el pedido 2 pueda tener por ejemplo 5 items. Gracias!

Comment: Si estas desarrollando quiere decir que estás trabajando en ello, por lo que te sugiero que copies tu código como texto y lo pegues en tu pregunta una vez la edites y sobre él, expliques lo que deseas obtener. Creo que tu pregunta no es lo suficientemente detallada para poder responderse. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tratas de hacer puedes buscar tutoriales en internet con el nombre de  "django inline formset"

Puedes probar esto.

https://github.com/CleitonDeLima/django-easy-formset